# Is $X$ measurable and $h\circ X$ integrable?

Tags: measure-theory

The Markov-inequality says:

> > Let $h\colon\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be monotonously increasing function, so that $h\circ X\in\mathcal{L}_{\mu}^1$ for a non-negative random variable $X$. Then for any $a>0$ it is
> >     $$
> > \mu(\left\{\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega>a\right\})\leq\frac{1}{h(a)}\int 1_{\left\{X>a\right\}}h\circ X\, d\mu.
> > $$

Now the task is to prove the following two statements:

> > Let $f$ be an integrable function and $\varepsilon > 0$. Then
> >     $$
> > \mu(\lvert f\rvert > \varepsilon)\leq\varepsilon^{-1}\int\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu~~~(1)
> > $$
> >     and
> >     $$
> > \mu(\lvert f-\int f\, d\mu\rvert >\varepsilon)\leq\varepsilon^{-2}\int\lvert f-\int f\, d\mu\rvert^2\, d\mu~~~~~(2)
> > $$

*Proof*

**(1)** In order to prove (1) just use the Markov-inequality above with $X:=\lvert f\rvert$ and $h=\text{id}$.

**(2)**

The professor wrote in the script:

Set $X:=\lvert f-\int f\, d\mu\rvert$ and $h(x)=x^2$ and use the Markov-inequality above.

But I do not see that

(i) $X$ is a random variable, i.e. measurable

(i) that $h\circ X\in\mathcal{L}_{\mu}^1$

Could you please explain that to me?

Greetings

Miro

Comment: What do you mean by "Is $\int f d\mu$ measurable"? What kind of mathematical object is $\int f d\mu$? Is it a function?

Comment: It is a real number or a complex number. If it is a real number, okay, then $\lvert f-\text{const}\rvert$ is a measurable function. What, if it is a complex number?

Comment: If it is complex, it is still only shifting your function by a constant

Comment: Both are measurable: Constants are measurable, sums of measurable functions are measurable, absolute values of measurable functions are measurable and compositions of measurable and continuous functions are also measurable. In your attempt however you seem to try to show that they are *integrable*.

Comment: Integrable is not the same as measurable.

Comment: I want to know if $X$ is measurable and if $h\circ X$ is integrable.

Comment: @MTurgeon How do you mean that? Which shifting?

Comment: $f-\mathrm{const}$ is what I mean by $f$ is being shifted by a constant